# How to describe someone speaking in pain?

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine someone gets hit heavily, or is in excruciating pain; when they try to speak, they sound like they have a sore throat, they are probably cringing.

Mumbling or muttering is speaking with less volume, inaudibly and mostly out of exhaustion. But I am looking for the speech of someone groaning in pain.

What is a word for that?

Comment: What's wrong with *groaned (a low, mournful sound uttered in pain or grief)*? It's a good word.

Comment: The use of less traditional report (or even quote) verbs is now well established: He groaned / shrieked that he had broken his leg / He groaned / shrieked "I've broken my leg".

Answer (score 4):

"Laboured" speech might fit your need.

Answer (score 4):

How about **croaking**?

> “No. More,” he croaked, so hoarse he was not certain he had even spoken. (G. R. R. Martin)

Comment: +1 *Croak* is particularly good as it's a slang synonym for "dying."

Comment: *Croak* is particularly bad, as it's slang for "dying".

Answer (score 0):

Adding to d'alar'cop's excellent answer:

**Struggling to speak**

**Sputtering** It implies ineffectively trying to spit out words.

> He tried to speak but the words came sputtering out of him.

**Stammering** This usually implies stuttering as a speech pathology, but it can also be a natural reaction to severe pain.

> After getting shot in the foot, all he could do was stammer in pain, unable to say what happened.

Comment: *Stammering in pain* got **20 hits** on Google, including this beaut: *Imagine this child smearing blood on the walls with this tumor stammering in pain and the parents do nothing. Social injustice is indoctrination.* *Sputtering in pain* got three pages, one entry being **Sputtering in pain, you say, "Banana"** Imagine a pain rating scale with the descriptions "...Sputtering (5); Spewing (6); Stammering (7); Squealing (8); Screaming (9); Shrieking (10)" Oy, vey, these people are here to examine English Language and **Usage**!

Comment: @Susan does that mean that "banana" is *not* your safe word?  The question was not how to describe pain, but how to describe *talking* while in excruciating pain.

Comment: (as you say) hahahahahahahahahahahahaha! Good one! Really, if it's not the safe word, it should be!!! (And my pain scale is how the patient is vocalizing their pain. As in, "YOWwwwwww" he squealed.) But thanks for the laugh. :)

Comment: @DavidM You seem to have overlooked "swearing" ;)

Comment: @nxx Absolutely. Although, that describes the semantic content more than the sound.

Comment: @DavidM Not if you're in a lot of pain!

Comment: @nxx I don't deny it. My point being:  you can swear in a pleasing tone, you can grunt swears, you can sputter swears, etc.

Comment: @DavidM I wasn't serious. Just your "stammering in pain" made me think of "swearing in pain" - sometimes they sound much alike.

Answer (score 0):

When someone is in great pain, it is hard to speak. So it comes out like a sharp whisper. So the verb you're looking for is *hissed*. "I think I broke my leg," he hissed.

Comment: I'd say more of a shriek.